# MS ACCESS 2007 VBA : DAO recordset....how can I view all the "fields" in the returned collection

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, dao

so if i do a SQL statement like so:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblMain"

     set rs = currentdb.openrecordset(sql)
```

what method can i use to view every "field name" in this collection i have just created. i am getting some very strange error stating that the item is not found in this collection.

i know the field exists in the table, i have triple checked the spelling everywhere when i reference it, and the SQL should be pulling everything, but i want to see it.

is there a debug.print method to see all these fields

thanks
Justin

Comment: @Justin  You seem to be a diligent student about this stuff.  So, just for grins, take Raj's answer and adapt it to use a "For Each ... Next" loop to iterate through the fields collection of your recordset.

Comment: ah yes!! i used a msgbox to through each name up! cool!

Comment: @Hans....yeah i am trying to learn as much as I can about it. I want to get to .NET & C#. But I am figuring this will be a good background once I get into that stuff??? we'll see.

Comment: Programming in VBA in Access will not be a preparation for .NET or C# any more than the course in BASIC I had in 1982 was a preparation for VBA in Access. You learn the basics of control structures, runtime vs. compile-time, etc., but nothing else transfers.

Comment: oh...well i guess the most i can say in terms of transferring is that I will at least get used researching "how to do" and learning on my own??? I am sure the resources for SQL Server, ASP.NET, C# Windows Forms, WPF, ADO, etc....is probably out there just like this. Though I most honestly admit that this particular website has helped me out quite a bit.....especially HansUp, Remou, Tony and David Fenton. You guys are like my Access/VBA professors!! so thanks!

Comment: On behalf of HansUp, Remou, David Fenton and me I think you for your kind words.

Comment: Well, Access can be a good preparation in understand database design, but that's not a .NET/C# issue. And, of course, if you follow the sample databases and templates that come with Access, you'll end up doing lots of terrible things that don't transfer to other dialects of SQL nor to server-based data engines (e.g., binding a form to an entire table). You need to keep track of what's idiosyncratic in Access/Jet/ACE SQL compared to other SQL variants. But it's a great way to learn normalization and other basic db topics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate through the fields collection of the recordset.

Code is OTTOMH

```
Dim NumFields as Integer

For NumFields = 0 to rs.Fields.Count -1
    Debug.Print Rs.Fields(NumFields).Name
Next
```

Alternately, you can set a breakpoint at `set rs = currentdb.openrecordset(sql)` and then as soon as the statement executes, right-click on `rs`, choose **add watch** and view the whole thing in the **Watches** window.

Answer (score 9):

This is a variation on the other answers, but I believe it's better to use a For/Each loop than a counter:

```
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim fld As DAO.Field

  Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblMain")
  For Each fld In rs.Fields
    Debug.Print fld.Name
  Next fld
  Set fld = Nothing
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that will look for a field containing the string you specify in every table in an Access database (except System and Attached Tables) and write it to text files:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim bFinished As Boolean
Dim sFieldName As String
Dim iPosition, z, x As Integer
Dim bRetVal  As Boolean
Dim tdTemp As TableDef
Dim iDatabaseNumbers As Integer


Const FIELD_TO_FIND = "FieldName"


Set db = CurrentDb

Open Left(db.Name, Len(db.Name) - 4) & "_" & FIELD_TO_FIND & ".txt" For Output As #1

    For x = 0 To db.TableDefs.Count - 1

        Set tdTemp = db.TableDefs(x)
        bRetVal = IIf(tdTemp.Attributes And dbSystemObject, False, True)
        If bRetVal Then
            bRetVal = IIf(tdTemp.Attributes And dbAttachedTable, False, True)
        End If

        If bRetVal Then
            Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(db.TableDefs(x).Name)
                If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
                    For z = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1

                        sFieldName = rs.Fields(z).Name
                        If InStr(1, sFieldName, FIELD_TO_FIND, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                            Print #1, db.TableDefs(x).Name
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next z
                End If
        End If
    Next x

Close #1

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

You could adjust accordingly to make it do what you need.